# How do I add a custom font to a Cocoapod?

Tags: iphone, ios, uifont, cocoapods

I want to use a custom font within a Cocoapod, but I can't find anything on using a custom font within a static library. As there is no info.plist file, there is no where to tell the app what font to use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17):

There is a way of using a custom font without adding anything to the plist file.

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    NSURL *fontURL = [bundle URLForResource:<#fontName#> withExtension:@"otf"/*or TTF*/];
    NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fontURL];
    CFErrorRef error;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
    CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
    if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
        NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
    }
    CFSafeRelease(font);
    CFSafeRelease(provider);
```

You also need the `CFSafeRelease` function for this to work.

```
void CFSafeRelease(CFTypeRef cf) {
    if (cf != NULL) {
        CFRelease(cf);
    }
}
```

Source: [Loading iOS fonts dynamically](https://marco.org/2012/12/21/ios-dynamic-font-loading).

Swift equivalent:

```
extension UIFont {
    static func registerFont(bundle: Bundle, fontName: String, fontExtension: String) -> Bool {
        guard let fontURL = bundle.url(forResource: fontName, withExtension: fontExtension) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't find font \(fontName)")
        }

        guard let fontDataProvider = CGDataProvider(url: fontURL as CFURL) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't load data from the font \(fontName)")
        }

        guard let font = CGFont(fontDataProvider) else {
            fatalError("Couldn't create font from data")
        }

        var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
        let success = CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)
        guard success else {
            print("Error registering font: maybe it was already registered.")
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: but then you can't use the fonts in Storyboards, right? Unless you load all the custom fonts during startup...

Comment: Since this is being sent over in a Cocoapod, and the idea is to have the font immediately available to those that consume the pod, when and where would `registerFont` be called?

Comment: @RIP.Ben.Franklin anywhere in the code of your library/pod

Answer (score 13):

For those of you finding this in 2018+, I got custom fonts to work **with** interface builder support (XCode 9) with these two steps:

1. Add your fonts to the resource bundle of your framework (in the .podspec file)

   ```
   s.resources = "PodName/**/*.{ttf}"
   ```
2. Load fonts at runtime using Adam's answer above

   ```
   #import <CoreText/CoreText.h>

   void CFSafeRelease(CFTypeRef cf) { // redefine this
     if (cf != NULL) {
       CFRelease(cf);
     }
   }


   + (void) loadFonts {
     NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.classForCoder];
     NSURL *bundleURL = [[frameworkBundle resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"PodName.bundle"];
     NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];

     NSURL *fontURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"HindMadurai-SemiBold" withExtension:@"ttf"];
     NSData *inData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fontURL];
     CFErrorRef error;
     CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)inData);
     CGFontRef font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider);
     if (!CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)) {
         CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(error);
         NSLog(@"Failed to load font: %@", errorDescription);
         CFRelease(errorDescription);
     }
     CFSafeRelease(font);
     CFSafeRelease(provider);
   }
   ```
3. Run pod install

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for this answer.  It's working pretty well for me so far.  One question...  When did you end up calling the loadFonts method?

Comment: I'm building an SDK so I ended up throwing it in an initialization method where the api key gets set, etc that i can be relatively certain will only be called once and guaranteed before anything in my library gets presented

Comment: Well, it seemed to work in the simulator, but for some reason the fonts don't load when I run it on the device.  Did you happen to run into this problem also, or did it "just work"?

Comment: Just a path problem.  Works now :)

Comment: Don't forget to run 'pod install' after editing your podspec

Answer (score 12):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to provide a font with your Cocoapod, and you intent the iOS apps which include the pod to be able to use your custom font.

This `post_install` hook seems to work:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  # ...
  s.resources = "Resources/*.otf"
  # ...
  s.post_install do |library_representation|
    require 'rexml/document'

    library = library_representation.library
    proj_path = library.user_project_path
    proj = Xcodeproj::Project.new(proj_path)
    target = proj.targets.first # good guess for simple projects

    info_plists = target.build_configurations.inject([]) do |memo, item|
      memo << item.build_settings['INFOPLIST_FILE']
    end.uniq
    info_plists = info_plists.map { |plist| File.join(File.dirname(proj_path), plist) }

    resources = library.file_accessors.collect(&:resources).flatten
    fonts = resources.find_all { |file| File.extname(file) == '.otf' || File.extname(file) == '.ttf' }
    fonts = fonts.map { |f| File.basename(f) }

    info_plists.each do |plist|
      doc = REXML::Document.new(File.open(plist))
      main_dict = doc.elements["plist"].elements["dict"]
      app_fonts = main_dict.get_elements("key[text()='UIAppFonts']").first
      if app_fonts.nil?
        elem = REXML::Element.new 'key'
        elem.text = 'UIAppFonts'
        main_dict.add_element(elem)
        font_array = REXML::Element.new 'array'
        main_dict.add_element(font_array)
      else
        font_array = app_fonts.next_element
      end

      fonts.each do |font|
        if font_array.get_elements("string[text()='#{font}']").empty?
          font_elem = REXML::Element.new 'string'
          font_elem.text = font
          font_array.add_element(font_elem)
        end
      end

      doc.write(File.open(plist, 'wb'))
    end
  end
```

The hook finds the user project, and in the first target (you probably can complete this solution by asking CocoaPods to give you the real target) it looks for its `Info.plist` file(s) (normally there is only one). Finally it looks for the `UIAppFonts` key of the file, creates it if not found, and fill the array with the font names if they are not already there.

Comment: That's some serious Pod-fu you have going on there.

Comment: Somehow my spec is invalidate by `pod spec lint`. But it works and it adds the custom font after installing, any pointers for that?

Comment: No, not without the error, open another question detailing your error, and what you have tried, otherwise it will be hard to help you.

Comment: post_install hook is deprecated so cannot use it, is it wright? https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1637

Comment: @SreeHarsha: yes, you cannot use this solution anymore and you will need another way to solve it, like the issue you link points to.

Comment: @yonosoytu can you update this info in the post, it will be helpful for other people

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5 implementation**

I was able to solve this by creating the below class in my Cocoapod, then just calling `CustomFonts.loadAll()` from my main app's `AppDelegate.swift`. After that I can just use a font like this in my app:

`let myFont = CustomFonts.Style.regular.font`

Note that the `Style` enum is not necessary, just a convenient way to separate concerns. You could also just call:

`let myFont = UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-SemiBold", size: 14)`

```swift
import CoreText

public class CustomFonts: NSObject {

  public enum Style: CaseIterable {
    case mono
    case regular
    case semibold
    public var value: String {
      switch self {
      case .mono: return "SourceCodePro-Medium"
      case .regular: return "SourceSansPro-Regular"
      case .semibold: return "SourceSansPro-SemiBold"
      }
    }
    public var font: UIFont {
      return UIFont(name: self.value, size: 14) ?? UIFont.init()
    }
  }

  // Lazy var instead of method so it's only ever called once per app session.
  public static var loadFonts: () -> Void = {
    let fontNames = Style.allCases.map { $0.value }
    for fontName in fontNames {
      loadFont(withName: fontName)
    }
    return {}
  }()

  private static func loadFont(withName fontName: String) {
    guard
      let bundleURL = Bundle(for: self).url(forResource: "[CococpodName]", withExtension: "bundle"),
      let bundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL),
      let fontURL = bundle.url(forResource: fontName, withExtension: "ttf"),
      let fontData = try? Data(contentsOf: fontURL) as CFData,
      let provider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData),
      let font = CGFont(provider) else {
        return
    }
    CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, nil)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, idk if it can be an answer, but you can also
look to cocoapod that has needed font, like this: 
https://github.com/parakeety/GoogleFontsiOS

Library contains many fonts, i needed Chivo, so i added pod 'GoogleFontsiOS/Chivo'
and used it instead of writing font-loading code by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The function `CTFontManagerRegisterFontsForURL` makes life more easier.